# IIS 7 Site using HTTPS not Accessible from Outside Internet (is accessible from intranet)

Tags: ssl, iis-7, https

I am trying to set up an HTTPS site on IIS 7. I have added the certificate, set up the appropriate bindings and the site is accesible from within my company's intranet, however no one from the outside internet can access it. I have a 1:1 NAT forward set up for port 443 that should route requests to the IP address for my server. I have the same situation for port 80 and don't have any issues with http sites being accessible.

Any suggestions for what I might be missing here?

UPDATE:

As it turns out, the company that manages my company's firewall had added the exception for https and 443, and the correct routing, but hadn't added an exception for the process that handles https.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on http://serverfault.com/ - this may lead to better and quicker answers.

Comment: What do you mean it's not accessible?   Externally, are you able to telnet to port 443?

Comment: The error I am getting is "The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 30000 ms". I can't telnet to port 443.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, from outside, use telnet to see if you can even get to the port from outside:

```
telnet <host name or ip> 443
```

Note the space before the port.
If the telnet screen goes fully black, w cursor in top left, you can connect, so it is an iis issue.

If telnet just sits there, it is trying to connect but can't. It may finally throw "connection refused" or "could not connect." This means the problem is on the physical firewall (which needs the inbound path opened) or on the iis server itself (in its firewall or iis config)

In this case, next step:
Do the telnet operation on the IIS server itself, and from the same network as IIS (e.g. not through the firewall).

-- If this works: The problem is the network firewall config

-- If this does not work, you need to check the firewall on the IIS server itself (the windows firewall), and the IIS config itself

Note, on windows 7 and vista, telnet may not be present out of the box. Google how to enable it.

Comment: Thanks man, this is helpful. I can't telnet in; it just hangs and than says "Connection is refused". 

Our firewall is handled by a third party company, and they swear that 443 is open...if that is true it would need to be the IIS config?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I still don't have it working, but telnet does work from the IIS. The 3rd party that manages our firewall says that requests on 443 should be open and routing to my server. At this point I am pretty sure they missed something.